# percentile formula error in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to apply a formula through VBA for a particular range. This is the code in my VBA editor:

```
Sheets("WBR45").Range("AE105").Formula = "=PERCENTILE.INC(TP!$A$3:$A$30:$B$3:$B$30:$C$3:$C$30:$E$3:$E$30,50%)*24"
```

And the below formula gets updated in the destination cell when this is run:

```
=PERCENTILE.INC(TP!$A$3:$A$30:$B$3:$B$30:$C$3:$C$30:$E$3:$E$30,50%)*24
```

But I get an error in the destination cell as #VALUE!.

And when I click on "Show Calculation steps", only this part of the formula is underlined :

```
TP!$A$3:$A$30:$B$3:$B$30
```

I have no idea what is wrong with this simple formula. Can someone please take a look

Comment: Are all your data cells in sheet `TP`?

Comment: Yes in that particular range as above in the code

Comment: Are you **really** wanting the function to operate on cells A3:E30 (including column D)?  Or do you want to only operate on the cells in columns A,B,C and E?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly I have no clue about what you're doing with this, but this may fix it:

```
"=PERCENTILE.INC(TP!$A$3:$A$30:TP!$B$3:$B$30:TP!$C$3:$C$30:TP!$E$3:$E$30,50%)*24"
```

Comment: @walterwhile and/or A.S.H., can you explain how a reference like `TP!$A$3:$A$30:TP!$B$3:$B$30:TP!$C$3:$C$30:TP!$E$3:$E$30` works? I tried variations of this and found that it acted the same as `$A$3:$E$30`--that is, the `PERCENTILE.INC` function included values in column D (if there were any).

Comment: @vknowles yes it is the same in this case. Sometimes a range might be a union of multiple ranges in which case you may need to specify the parent of each area.

Comment: @vknowles - Now I see what you mean - the multiple `:`s get ignored and only the first and last cell is used to determine the range, e.g. `Sum(A1:C1,D4:E4)` will sum the values in cells `A1`, `B1`, `C1`, `D4`, and `E4`, but `Sum(A1:C1:D4:E4)` acts as `Sum(A1:E4)`.

Comment: @vknowles - No - my comment was not quite right - that example works that way, but `Sum(A6:C7:D4:E4)` acts as if it is `Sum(A4:E7)`, so Excel sets top-left based on minimum row / column from the 1st, 3rd, 5th, etc parameters, and sets bottom-right based on maximum row / column from the 2nd, 4th, 6th, etc parameters.

Comment: @YowE3K, interestingly, this *curious* syntax if it starts with a sheet `name!`, you need to feed it the name every about two tokens.

Comment: I assume it is using each pair to define a rectangle and then, just as you can't use something stupid like `ws1.Range(ws2.Cells(1, 1), ws2.Cells(5,5))` in VBA, it is insisting that all those rectangles exist on the one sheet.  So you can't have one rectangle such as `TP!A3:A30` and another rectangle of `B3:B30` (which is therefore on a different sheet).  But why it doesn't just use a syntax which puts the sheetname first, and only first, is beyond understanding.

Comment: @YowE3K Well, as it seems, this `:` operator looks consistent. The way it works, somehow, it yields the *"minimal spanning rectangle!"*. After all, this is what happens with a single `A1:E4`, so, same it does with `A1:E7:F4`, which equals `A1:F7`. That is, *"minimal spanning rectangle"*. Amazing!

Comment: But again, curiously, if you start it with a `sheetName!`, you need to *remind it* that name every two tokens :D

Comment: Weird, just plain **weird**!!  And typing something like `=SUM(B3:E16:H7:J1)` in Excel switches the `H7:J1` to `H1:J7`, so it is **trying** make pairs of the references.  (It looks really strange if you edit that formula, and it highlights the individual rectangles, but you have to stop and think that it is actually using stuff outside the highlighted areas :D)

Comment: I don't see any changes in a formula I type into the formula bar. If I type `=SUM(A1:A5:C1:C5:E1:E2:F3:F4)`, it highlights the four areas as if they were separate ranges. After I press ENTER, the formula remains the same but it behaves as if it were `=SUM(A1:F5)`. See also my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41653917/non-contiguous-range-specification-in-formula).

Comment: @vknowles - try changing that formula to `=SUM(A5:A1:C5:C1:E2:E1:F4:F3)` and you will notice that Excel will change it back - it always tries to make the first reference a "top-left" and the second reference a "bottom-right".  And, although Excel displays the individual rectangles while you are editing the formula, it is completely ignoring them when doing the calculations.  It was your original comment to this question that led us to notice this weird behaviour.

Comment: @YowE3K - I see what you mean. I didn't notice that your example had the corners reversed.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have three errors in your formula:

1. You are using `:` to separate ranges instead of `,`
2. You are not specifying which sheet the second, third and fourth ranges refer to, therefore it is defaulting to the sheet on which the formula occurs (i.e. sheet "WBR45")
3. Multiple ranges will need to be enclosed within brackets `(...)` in order to be passed as a single range.

If you are trying to have your function operate on the range A3:C30 together with the range E3:E30 (i.e. A3:E30 but ignoring column D), with those ranges being on the "TP" worksheet, I believe that you need to change your formula to

```
Sheets("WBR45").Range("AE105").Formula = "=PERCENTILE.INC((TP!$A$3:$A$30,TP!$B$3:$B$30,TP!$C$3:$C$30,TP!$E$3:$E$30),50%)*24"
```

or, slightly simplified

```
Sheets("WBR45").Range("AE105").Formula = "=PERCENTILE.INC((TP!$A$3:$C$30,TP!$E$3:$E$30),50%)*24"
```