# "Non-contiguous" range specification in formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[2018-08-01: See new material near bottom of post.]

I just ran across a Q-n-A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41652483/percentile-formula-error-in-vba) that included an example of a function referencing a range using a specification I had not seen before. I played around with it a little and discovered that most Excel functions will return a value when using this kind of reference:

```
=SUM(A1:A5:C1:C5:E1:E2:F3:F4)
```

Notice all the ":"s in there.

With the cursor in the formula bar, those non-contiguous cells are highlighted, **as if** only those cells would be totaled. However, when I experimented, I discovered that it is equivalent to this formula:

```
=SUM(A1:F5)
```

However, this formula does what I expect:

```
=SUM(A1:A5,C1:C5,E1:E2,F3:F4)
```

Example: I have the range A1:F5 defined as:

```
--  A   B   C   D   E   F

1   1   2   3   4   5   6

2   2   4   6   8   10  12

3   3   6   9   12  15  18

4   4   8   12  16  20  24

5   5   10  15  20  25  30
```

The formula results are:

=SUM(A1:F5)  is 315

=SUM(A1:A5:C1:C5:E1:E2:F3:F4) is 315

=SUM(A1:A5,C1:C5,E1:E2,F3:F4) is 117

This illustrates my point that the first two seem to be equivalent, and the third "correct" way of defining a discontiguous range gives a different result (but what I would expect).

I looked around here and elsewhere on the Internet and found no relevant discussion.

So, my questions:

1. Is that odd range reference of any real use?
2. is it really a valid sort of range reference?

---

[New material 2018-08-01]

@YowE3K wondered what would happen with an **odd** number of cells. Here is my example:

```
--  A   B   C  

1   1   1   1   

2   1   1   1   

3   1   1   1   

4   1   1   1
```

Now, in a faraway cell, I enter this formula:

```
=SUM(A1:B3:$C$2)
```

Then if I drag the formula around, it creates interesting results, basically the 3-row, 2-column range extended to a rectangular range that always includes the fixed cell. The smallest sum you can ever get in this example is 3. Try it and see.

This shows a glimmer of something useful, though I haven't come up with a concrete use for it yet.

Comment: I guess it's useful because it automatically gives you the bounding box of a multiarea range (would be tricky to calculate it manually in a formula). Otherwise I have not seen it either.

Comment: @GSerg - There has been an interesting discussion at the original question (link in my OP above).

Comment: I can't think of many uses for that sort of syntax, but **perhaps** something like `=SUM(A1:A10:A$9)` (where one cell was absolute, but the others were a relative range) **might** be useful somewhere.

Comment: @YowE3K - I like that idea. I set up a sample worksheet and will play around with it. It gives interesting patterns when you copy the formula around.

Comment: I used "Evaluate Formula" on "SUM(A1:B3:$C$2)", and Excel converted it to "SUM($A$1:$C$3)". There are two takeaways: 1) the range is converted to a rectangle with dimensions that will accommodate all referenced cells, 2) the new reference will always include the cell that had an absolute reference. An interesting property of this is that the relative reference portion effectively defines a "minimum-sized" dimension. As you drag the formula around it can expand, always including the absolute reference, but when the relative and absolute references intersect, a minimum size will be maintained.

Answer (score 1):

1. When separated by a comma, simpler is better.  Avoid referencing subsets within the same rectangular block that Excel would create if you only selected the upper left and bottom right of the region in question.
2. No, there are not too many practical exercises that warrant this additional complexity (when referencing cells separated by a colon only).  I read a comment/proposed response by someone who suggested there is use, depending on the data structure.  I advise that individual seek a better format/ layout of data before using an overly complex referencing regime/strategy
3. RE: separation by comma: Yes, there are numerous practical and valid exercises that are being managed in  suitable fashion

**Background / detail**

You have asked two questions: i.e. pertaining to 1) validity of 'odd referencing' and 2) potential use (paraphrased).

Re: validity - going back to basics, when you sum the whole are you are simply referencing the upper most left and bottom most right cells - Excel automatically creates a 'perimeter' to encompass any and all cells separated by a colon.  This perimeter is always constructed to form a rectangle (the square being a special type of rectangle).  You can actually 'force' Excel to keep these cells separated initially, i.e. the first and second summations are identical (parametrically, and in terms of their result):

[image: Figure 1) Usual summation of a rectangular enclosed block]

[image: Figure 2) Identical variation depicting upper left and bottom right cells]

Probably the most important implication/consequence of this is as follows:

- You cannot double-sum no matter how many 'sub-ranges', disparate / overlapping or otherwise, PROVIDED these are separated by a colon.  For instance, the following gives exactly the same solution as the first 2 figures:

[image: Figure 3) Union of cells within outer perimeter]

However, for most practical applications, it would be rare and odd to require multi-subset referencing (especially when it comes to summation).  I could envisage something like this when using various subsets that are separated with a comma.

Generally, parsimony/simplicity in formulation is required (for auditability, reviewability, validation, computationally speed, error mitigation, and so on).

I believe it would be quite challenging to concoct / fathom a scenario where referencing several subsets within (or across) tables of data served a cause that couldn't be achieved using the simple, straightforward referencing per Figure 1).

In fact, it would require a highly bespoke exercise/structure to justify something like the summation shown in Figure 3, and as a long-serving manager who reviews excel models almost on a daily basis, I would certainly advise against constructing a summation that referenced in this manner.

The more that I consider, it, multiple referencing of this manner impedes functionality.  For instance, using the referencing style in Figures 1-2 allows one to take summation across multiple (adjacent) sheets (which I'm not a big fan of because any sheet that's placed between Sheets 4 and 2 will be included in the summation, which can lead to errors):

```
=SUM(Sheet4:Sheet2!A1:F5)
```

Where Sheets 2, 3, and 4 contain identical values to those you provided, which yields 945 (=315 x 3) as one would expect. Doing this for version 3 results in #Value! (not even Excel likes it!).

Now, in terms of separation by commas, this is an entirely different thing but involves similar 'mechanics' under the hood.  Excel will only 'perimeter-fence' cells separated by a colon, and it will create several 'ring-fenced' rectangular perimeters, one for each group of (colon-separated) cells that are separated by a comma.

This 'setup' has a number of practical uses: it allows non-contiguous groups of cells to be summed; different conditions can be placed on each e.g. here's a function that sums all even numbers on the left hand side, and all odd numbers on the right:

```
=SUM(A1:C5*(MOD(A1:C5,2)=0),D1:F5*(MOD(D1:F5,2)<>0))
```

This yields 99 (if I haven't mixed up the mod divisor/operand:).  PS - at this point I realised I copied your values incorrectly and inadvertently included the row labels as a column.  So the 99 is based upon the 'correct' values which reconciles to results you've shown.

Of course, I could take the sum of the left & right side (without any such conditions, or with some condition that will also be satisfied, e.g. mod(a,b) < 0), where each half is separated by a comma. Of course this would yield the exact same overall result as summing the entire region like shown in Figures 1-3.

So, when separated by a comma, Excel treats this exactly the same as Figure 1-3 BUT it only does so in respect of each 'subset' of 'colon' separated cells.  Here, duplication/overlapping or omitted ranges do count / make a difference.

There is no 'odd' form of referencing when it comes to colon or comma, there is good/best practice, but with the infinite different possibilities/data table constructs, initiatives and uses/models etc/ there will undoubtedly be *some* use for complicated forms of straightforward summations (when separated by a colon);  I see these as being rare/far-between and advise against a complicated set up if it can be avoided.

However, I see greater application / purpose for a similar construct with 2/3 or more subsets separated by a comma.  In fact, this effectively achieves the same outcome as the status bar message (with summation statistics selected to 'display', i.e. after right-clicking and selecting it):

[image: Figure 4]

Answer (score 0):

1. Is that odd range reference of any real use? <-- Yes. Depending on the data structure you are working on, you may not have the privilege of adding an extra row/column in the sheet.
2. is it really a valid sort of range reference? <--- Since it works, yes. Regardless of whether it is properly documented or not. congratulations of you findings though. I'm learning new things too.  (:

Comment: I don't quite understand #1. Are you saying, perhaps the user does not have access to all the cells in A1:F5 but somehow using A1:A5:C1:C5:E1:E2:F3:F4 would get around such a problem? Can you provide an example? Thanks!

Comment: What I mean is.. normally (by my standard) you collect the odd range of data into 1 column > then perform operation on that column. It can be sum() index() average() or even index() & match(). But in some cases, (normally a company) that have many users/editor of the same file. adding/changing rows/columns is not an option.. then this may of defining odd cell range may ave the day. | Btw, I still prefer to use the proper `A1:A5,C1:C5,E1:E2,F3:F4` way of deining odd areas anyway.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't capture the issue. See my edit of the original question. Because the "proper" method you propose gives a different result, I still don't know whether there is any benefit to using the "improper" one.

Comment: Seems like a good candidate for [Obfuscated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Obfuscated_C_Code_Contest) excel code for me.. ( :  My hat's up for you on the 'explanation' excel file.. 5 star algo analysis you got there.. I'm impressed. However, IMHO I see that there is no extra benefit gained using the "improper" range definition. | Good Luck on finding a better answer though.  (:

Answer (score 0):

One possible use I have found is that INDIRECT() can be used in conjunction with this syntax. For example:

`=SUM(INDIRECT("a"&H11&":a"&I11):A1:C1:C4:D4:F1)`

where cells H11 and T11 have a value equal to the row. This allows for a variable range that has a minimum range.

If, as an example, I wanted to have a range that would update based on user input but included columns A & B and rows 1 & 2 I might use the following:

`=SUM(INDIRECT(H11&":"&I11):A1:A2:A1:B1)`

Thanks for sharing, I'll update if I find an opportunity to use it in a live formula in the future.