# Excel VBA To Add New Row If Condition Is Met

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I am attempting to write some VBA that will accomplish

> if row O is not null then copy all data to new row, then in current row clear columns I, J, K, L, M, N
>   in the newly inserted row clear columns O

The caveat I am not sure to account for is `-` throws a

> Type mismatch error

Here is the syntax that I am trying to work with

```
Sub BlueBell()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long, y
ReDim y(2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row)
For i = UBound(y) To LBound(y) Step -1
If Cells(i, "O") Then
    If Cells(i, "I") = "" And Cells(i, "K") = "" And Cells(i, "M") = "" Then
        GoTo DoNothing
    Else
        Rows(i).Copy
        Cells(i, "A").Insert
        Range("I" & i & ":J" & i & ":K" & i & ":L" & i & ":M" & i & ":N" & i & ":O" & i + 1).ClearContents
        GoTo DoNothing
    End If
End If
DoNothing:
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't use a string value as a boolean expression.  Try changing `If Cells(i, "O") Then` to `If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, "O").Value) Then`

Comment: That will no longer throw an error - but it is clearing cells on lines it should not?

Comment: It's clearing the wrong cells because of the use of the esoteric range definition of "Ix:Jx:Kx:Lx:Mx:Nx:Ox+1" - which really ends up meaning the range "Ix:Ox+1", but shouldn't be used.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/41653917/6535336 for some interesting comments about that sort of range definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from your error with using a string as a boolean expression, there are several things that can be changed in your code:

```
Sub BlueBell()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim i As Long  ', y() As Variant
    'ReDim y(2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row) 'Why use an array?
    For i = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row To 2 Step -1
        If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, "O").Value) Then
            'Avoid the use of GoTo
            If Cells(i, "I").Value <> "" Or _
               Cells(i, "K").Value <> "" Or _
               Cells(i, "M").Value <> "" Then
                Rows(i).Copy
                Cells(i, "A").Insert
                'Don't use a "Ix:Jx:Kx:Lx:Mx:Nx:Ox+1" range - it will lead to problems
                'because even really experienced users don't understand what it does
                Range("I" & i & ":N" & i).ClearContents
                Range("O" & i + 1).ClearContents
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    'It's a good habit to reset anything that you disabled at the start of your code
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Works to perfection!  Why to avoid use of GoTo? -- also not using an Array() speeds up the code!

Comment: @IcyPopTarts - (a) `GoTo` is a hangover from the old days when there were no block `If` statements.  It isn't specifically bad **if** you are careful in its use, but it is very easy to accidentally `GoTo` the inside of a loop, or to somewhere else inappropriate, and it makes code harder to debug (because you have to work backwards to find which part of your code is jumping to the label) - so it is best to avoid it.

Comment: @IcyPopTarts  (b) Arrays would normally speed code up, if you read the information into an array, worked on it in the array, then wrote the array back to the worksheet - but you were only using the array so that you could do a `UBound` and `LBound`.