# Feeding Multiple Distant Cells as One Array in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have the following table in Excel.

```
   A B C D                        E
1  i x y mu                       sigma
2  0 1 2 =average(b$1:b1,b3:b$12) =stdev.s(b$1:b1,b3:b$12)
3  1 3 4 =average(b$1:b2,b4:b$12) =stdev.s(b$1:b2,b4:b$12)
4  2 2 1 =average(b$1:b3,b5:b$12) =stdev.s(b$1:b3,b5:b$12)
5  3 1 2 ...                      ...
6  4 2 5
7  5 4 7
8  6 8 1
9  7 2 3
10 8 5 9
11 9 1 3
```

The ith mu calculates the average without the ith observation—the leave-one-out average. I can also calculate the leave-one-out standard deviations, but how can I do this for the leave-one-out correlations then? `correl` requires two arrays and I cannot feed two or more distant cells as one array using commas. Can I input non-consecutive cells as one array? For example, I tried `=correl((b$1:b1,b3:b$12),(c$1:c1,c3:c$12))`, but failed. Thanks for your reading.

Comment: What about `=correl((b$1:b1:b3:b$12),(c$1:c1:c3:c$12))` (note how the commas in the ranges are now colons)?

Comment: @JohnColeman returns the full range including the row that should be skipped.

Comment: @ScottCraner Strange. When you enter the formula in manually, the cells that you mention are what is highlighted on the spreadsheet, as if that row *is* skipped. Arguably there is a bit of a bug here. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41653917/4996248) and thought that perhaps this would work. +1 for your nice answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because CORREL takes arrays we can use an array formula:

```
=CORREL(INDEX(B:B,N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF(ROW($B$2:$B$11)<>ROW(),ROW($B$2:$B$11)*{1,1}))))),INDEX(C:C,N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF(ROW($C$2:$C$11)<>ROW(),ROW($C$2:$C$11)*{1,1}))))))
```

Use this easier array formula as per the OP(I overthought this):

```
=CORREL(IF(ROW($B$2:$B$11)=ROW(),"",$B$2:$B$11),IF(ROW($C$2:$C$11)=ROW(),"",$C$2:$C$11))
```

Being an array formula one needs to use Ctrl-shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

This will pass two arrays of only the numbers not on the row where the formula is placed.

[image]

---

Now, eventually when microsoft releases the dynamic array formula into Office 365 this can be simplified using `FILTER()`

```
=CORREL(FILTER($B$2:$B$11,ROW($B$2:$B$11)<>ROW()),FILTER($C$2:$C$11,ROW($C$2:$C$11)<>ROW()))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but what if simply `=correl(if(row(b2:b11)=row(),"",b2:b11),if(row(c2:c11)=row(),"",c2:c11))` instead?

Comment: In fact, post your own answer with that formula I will remove it from mine.

Comment: This is helpful already. By the way, will the array formula way be the only solution? I'd like to avoid that as a bit slow.

Comment: That I can think of, it is the only way.