# Feeding Multiple Distant Cells as One Array—Another Case

Tags: excel

This is related to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58122966/feeding-multiple-distant-cells-as-one-array-in-excel), but a bit different. I have the following table including 6 variables—3 Xs and 3 Ys—with 10 observations each.

```
    A  B  C  D  E  F ...
1  X1 Y1 X2 Y2 X3 Y3
2   7  5  3  2  4  1
3   2  6  7  9  8  0
4   6  2  4  6  7  1
5   3  4  2  5  3  5
6   8  8  2  4  6  7
7   9  3  5  2  7  6
8   0  3  4  2  5  7
9   7  0  5  1  1  4
10  1  4  2  5  1  3
11  2  3  8  9  1  7
12                 =correl(E2:E11,F2:F11)
```

Suppose I want to obtain the `correl` between `X` and `Y` rather than the `correl` between `X3` and `Y3` above. One primitive way is to vectorize the variables accordingly—that is, cut `C2:C11` and paste at `A12`, cut `D2:D11` and paste at `B12`, and so on. I wonder whether I can use `correl` without transforming this table. It seems neither colons nor parentheses work here. Thank you.

Comment: One approach would be to calculate a combined correlation based on the means, standard deviations, correlations and sample sizes for each pair of columns using the method outlined in this paper https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.3758%2FBF03334158.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a long formula:

```
=CORREL(INDEX(A2:F11,N(IF({1},MOD(ROW(A1:B30)-1,10)+1)),N(IF({1},INT((ROW(A1:B30)-1)/10)*2+1))),INDEX(A2:F11,N(IF({1},MOD(ROW(A1:B30)-1,10)+1)),N(IF({1},INT((ROW(A1:B30)-1)/10)*2+2))))
```

(this array formula needs generalising for arbitrary size array)

[image]

**EDIT**

Here is the generalised formula for a 2D range of arbitrary size and shape (it does work with if(1... not if({1}... ):

```
=CORREL(INDEX(A2:F11,N(IF(1,MOD(ROW(A1:INDEX(B:B,ROWS(A2:F11)*COLUMNS(A2:F11)/2))-1,ROWS(A2:F11))+1)),N(IF(1,INT((ROW(A1:INDEX(B:B,ROWS(A2:F11)*COLUMNS(A2:F11)/2))-1)/ROWS(A2:B11))*2+1))),
INDEX(A2:F11,N(IF(1,MOD(ROW(A1:INDEX(B:B,ROWS(A2:F11)*COLUMNS(A2:F11)/2))-1,ROWS(A2:F11))+1)),N(IF(1,INT((ROW(AA1:INDEX(B:B,ROWS(A2:F11)*COLUMNS(A2:F11)/2))-1)/ROWS(A2:F11))*2+2))))
```

Both formulas need to be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for your help, but what's the function of `if({1},)`? I saw this approach in the previous question, but the code worked just with `n()` too.

Comment: Oh, I just understood this. Please ignore the question above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`CORREL` itself does not support the use of non contiguous ranges. There is a workaround for some functions (e.g.`COUNTIF` as described [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/countif-with-non-contiguous-range)) but I'm relatively sure they won't work on `CORREL`. You could work around that by writing your own user-defined function in VBA, but I'm not sure the result will be worth the hassle in your case.